# How to write this formula?

Tags: math-mode

How to write this formula in Latex？
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We are no do-it-for-me-service. Please provide a minimal example of what you've tried. If you don't know how to write a specific symbol, try Detexify.

Comment: Or consult http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution using `tikz` to draw the symbols (although I like egreg's solution better):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\lineheight}
\newcommand{\updateheight}{\settoheight{\lineheight}{A}}
\tikzset{ThreePoints/.style={circle, fill}}
\newcommand{\drawthreepoints}{%
    \node [ThreePoints] (first) at (0,0) {};
    \node [ThreePoints] (second) at (0.5,0.8) {};
    \node [ThreePoints] (third) at (-0.5,0.8) {};
}
\newcommand{\resizepoints}[1]{\updateheight\resizebox{!}{\lineheight}{#1}}
\newcommand{\threepoints}{\resizepoints{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawthreepoints
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\newcommand{\threepointsone}{\resizepoints{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawthreepoints
    \draw [line width=3pt] (third) -- (second);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\newcommand{\threepointstwo}{\resizepoints{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawthreepoints
    \draw [line width=3pt] (third) -- (second) -- (first);
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    d(G)=d(\threepoints)d(\threepoints,G)+d(\threepointsone)d(\threepointsone,G)+d(\threepointstwo)d(\threepointstwo,G)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's rather easy with `pict2e`. The argument to `\TR` is a three digit binary number, which sets draws the lines joining the dots; the first digit represents the top, then we proceed in clockwise order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\TR}[1]{\TR@aux#1000\@nil}
\def\TR@aux#1#2#3#4\@nil{%
  \,\vcenter{\hbox{\TR@aux@i{#1}{#2}{#3}}}\,%
}
\def\TR@aux@i#1#2#3{%
  \setlength\unitlength{.5em}%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.866)
  \put(0.5,0){\circle*{.4}}
  \put(0,0.866){\circle*{.4}}
  \put(1,0.866){\circle*{.4}}
  \ifnum#1=1 \polyline(0,0.866)(1,0.866) \fi
  \ifnum#2=1 \polyline(1,0.866)(0.5,0) \fi
  \ifnum#3=1 \polyline(0.5,0)(0,0.866) \fi
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
d(G)=
d(\TR{000})d(\TR{000},G)+
d(\TR{100})d(\TR{100},G)+
d(\TR{110})d(\TR{110},G)
\]

$\TR{000}\quad\TR{001}\quad\TR{010}\quad\TR{011}$

$\TR{100}\quad\TR{101}\quad\TR{110}\quad\TR{111}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could actually use `\Line`, here, instead of `\polyline`.  And what about a standard `\mathpalette` wrapper?

Comment: @GuM You looked in the manual, didn't you? `:-)` The `\mathpalette` thing is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[show frame]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, stackengine,adjustbox}

\newcommand{\threedots}{\!\begin{smallmatrix} \bullet\mkern10mu\bullet \\ \bullet \end{smallmatrix}\!}

\newcommand{\threedotsl}{\!\begin{smallmatrix}\bullet\mkern-4mu\mathord{\relbar\mkern-9mu\relbar}\mkern-4mu\bullet \\
 \bullet \end{smallmatrix}\!}

\newcommand{\threedotsll}{\!\stackMath\stackinset{r}{9.7pt}{c}{0pt}{\adjustbox{rotate=-4, origin=c, scale={1}{0.8}}{$ \not $}}%
{\begin{smallmatrix}\bullet\mkern-4mu\mathord{\relbar\mkern-9mu\relbar}\mkern-4mu\bullet \\
 \bullet \end{smallmatrix}}\!}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
d(G) = d\bigl(\threedots\bigr)d\bigl(\threedots, G\bigr) + d\bigl(\threedotsl\bigr)d\bigl(\threedotsl, G\bigr) + d\bigl(\threedotsll)d\bigl(\threedotsll, G)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]